# How can I deliver custom micrometer configuration for use by corporate internal microservices?

Tags: spring-boot-starter, observability

I want our internal corporate microservices to use recommended Observability configuration merely by adding in the build dependency.

One way to do this is with Spring Boot starter.  Assume the teams are using Spring Boot 3.1.x.

The common configuration would include an ObservationFilterHandler, and a RequestFilter, dependencies on the trace collection (e.g., zipkin), and a few application properties.  Simple on face, but I ran into some headwind.

Before I put in work to hammer out a spring boot starter for this, I just want a check.  Are there viable alternaives to this requirement other than a starter?